# Is it possible in ElasticSearch to have a _parent mapping that is of the same type as the child?

Tags: elasticsearch

Basically, is it possible to do this?

```
curl -XPOST http://esdev1-sn1:9200/test/tracking/_mapping -d '
{
  "tracking": {
    "_parent": {
      "type": "tracking"
    }
  }
}
'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically, nothing prevents you from doing this. Practically, figuring out routing might be an issue. Elasticsearch requires all children to be indexed in the same shard as parent. So, in your case if your index contains more than one shard then for any given document all its ancestors and descendants have to be indexed with the same `_routing` value.